# How does this statement check "T cannot be compared to nullptr"?

Tags: c++

```cpp
static_assert(
  std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<T>() != nullptr), bool>::value,
  "T cannot be compared to nullptr.");
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/pointers

Specifically:

1. What would the result of `decltype(std::declval<T>() != nullptr)` be, if T really cannot not be compared to nullptr?
2. Can I replace `!=` with `==` here?
3. Can I replace `std::is_convertible` with `std::is_same` here?

Comment: I would expect that, if `T` really cannot be compared to `nullptr`, that `std::declval<T>() != nullptr` would be a diagnosable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` cannot be compared to `nullptr`, the whole thing is ill-formed.

https://godbolt.org/z/eqehez

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    static_assert(
              std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<T>() != nullptr), bool>::value,
              "T cannot be compared to nullptr.");
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
}
```

This results in a compiler diagnostic, and not an assertion, *using Microsoft's own compiler*:

```
example.cpp
<source>(7): error C2446: '!=': no conversion from 'nullptr' to 'T'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
<source>(7): note: A native nullptr can only be converted to bool or, using reinterpret_cast, to an integral type
<source>(13): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void foo<int>(void)' being compiled
<source>(7): error C2955: 'std::is_convertible': use of class template requires template argument list
C:/data/msvc/14.28.29333/include\type_traits(354): note: see declaration of 'std::is_convertible'
<source>(7): error C2057: expected constant expression
Compiler returned: 2
```

It doesn't matter whether you use `!=` or `==` here. Whether you can use `is_same` is a moot point. This seems to answer the questions you asked. The overall purpose of this `static_assert` is somewhat unclear. I had a fleeting thought that this might occasionally encounter some evil `T` that overloads `==` and `!=` operators for comparing `T` with `std::nullptr_t`, which then returns something other than `bool`. This is a bit of a stretch, but is possible. I looked at that github repo, and that didn't appear to be the case. I think this test is broken.

Comment: At least, error points into code inside a `static_assert` That might still help to debug. Without having to create code to detect that `operator==` exists...